# how to to count the length of items in a table using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

could someone please help me with some code, i have an angular app with a datatable were i use ngFor to populate the datatable so now i want to count every column that have name apple and display the value on a card called apples

i tried writing a function like this:

```
let apples = [];
    getValues(item){
      item.apples.forEach(element => {
      this.apples.push(element);
      this.apples.length;
  });
```

then i tried displaying the value of the length

my expected out put is to have each card with the value of how many columns that have the names of a certain fruit eg apples: 8, peach: 3 and so on

Comment: Why can't you directly use `{{item.apples.length}}` on your card rather than calling a method just to iterate over apples array? Or do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Return the value and bind the function to your column,

```
getValues(item){
      item.apples.forEach(element => {
      this.apples.push(element);
  }); 
  return this.apples.length;
}
```

and bind as `{{getValues()}}`